# disable checkbox if input value is zero

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i have a list of check-boxes which is created dynamically and there is input field for each check box so i want to disable the check box if input field value is zero. below is my code

HTML code

```
<input class="check" id="check" name="check" type="checkbox"><label for="check">checkbox <input type="hidden" id="test" value="0" /></label>
<input class="check" id="check1" name="check1" type="checkbox"><label for="check1">checkbox1 <input type="hidden" id="test" value="6" /></label>
```

Jquery

```
if($("#test").val() == "0"){
    $('.check').attr("disabled", "disabled");
}
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5eE64/)

Comment: Please explain what isn't working.

Comment: you are using same id twice on same page!!

Comment: As you said "you want to disable the check box if input field value is zero" and your fiddle is doing the same. then what is the problem

Comment: I think he wants something like this http://jsfiddle.net/viphalongpro/5eE64/1/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You used twice `id=test` and JavaScript works with only the first of them.

Change `id=test` to `class=test`, or works with two differents `id`s.

Working code:

```
$('.test').each(function() {
    if ($(this).val() == '0') {
        $(this).parent().prev().attr('disabled', 'disabled');
    }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/cDD5L/

Answer (score 1):

```
$("input[type=hidden]").each(function() {
    if($(this).val()==0){ 
     $(this).parent().prev().attr('disabled', 'disabled');
 }                             
});
```

**Demo:**

http://jsfiddle.net/SxypS/

Answer (score 0):

Please use

```
$(function() {
  enable_cb();
  $("#group1").click(enable_cb);
});

function enable_cb() {
  if (this.checked) {
    $("input.group1").removeAttr("disabled");
  } else {
    $("input.group1").attr("disabled", true);
  }
}
```

It will work for you.

Let me know if still not work